# How to add an item GRUB 1.98?

Tags: grub

I am having trouble with GRUB version 1.98.

I have been using GRUB 0.97 for a long time and can do pretty much what I want with it.

It appears that the last version of Debian (6.0) installs GRUB 1.98. There are probably very good reasons for that upgrade, but nevertheless I have to say I am lost.

I just downloaded the linux kernel 2.6.38 and compiled it as usual. Now I don't know how to add this new kernel in the GRUB menu. I tried two or three ways on my own, but it all failed.

This used to be very easy when I was using  version 0.97. Can someone tell me what I need to do with  GRUB 1.98 ?

Thanks for any information.

Comment: Did you place the kernel in /boot/ and run "update-grub"?

Comment: I have just removed some OSs and still have entries in grub, I tried update-grub, but nothing happened. Using Debian-6, grub version: 1.98+20100804-14+squeeze1

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest building the kernel according to the [Debian way](http://wiki.debian.org/HowToRebuildAnOfficialDebianKernelPackage); this has many benefits and generally makes system administration much cleaner. Also your kernel will be installed automagically.

Comment: A good comment, but not an answer.